# Determine windows title from executable

Tags: windows

A program at the customers side with the title ".NET-BroadcastEventWindow.4.0.0.0.1400c58.0" blocks shutdown in rare cases.
Using "tasklist /fo list /v" i am not able to find the program on my test system. Seems it is not always running.

I like searching the file system (offline) for executables with this windows title.

1. Is the number at the end of the title a dynamic value or fixed ? Meaning has the program X with version Y always the same number ?
2. Is it possible to get the windows title offline from an executable file ? For example reading the properties.

Comment: "Is the number at the end of the title a dynamic value or fixed?" - This is application-specific.

Comment: Check these threads: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-withnet-broadcasteventwindow4000282af8c0/41a1437e-6156-4f19-96a7-748c6c6e8821 and https://www.vegascreativesoftware.info/us/forum/bug-report-broadcasteventwindow-4-0-0-0-error-message-on-shutdown--138488/  Since this is a .NET app, you might check if .NET framework has been updated, too.